# Google Translate offline translation

Tags: offline, google-translate

I downloaded tons of offline translation packages for Google Translate some time ago. Then at some point I must have done something, maybe an update, or a setting change (perhaps that Primary Language thing that kept popping up every time I opened Translate?), and suddenly my packages have all vanished! Moreover, when I go under the top-left corner dropdown menu and choose "Offline translation", I end up here:

[image]

after getting a message `Can't get offline packages list` (or that pops up after those two blue texts appear, that varies from time to time), and none of those is a link. How do I get my offline translation back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had the same problem. Just delete your app data and download them again.